# Django modelform save method: ERROR: syntax error at or near "args"

Tags: django, postgresql, django-database

I'm trying to save my model form. Django reurns `InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`

This is a problem in executing `INSERT` sql-query **which is generated by Django**. It looks like:

```
INSERT INTO "myapp_mymodel" ("title", ...) VALUES ("Test", ...) RETURNING "catalog_ad"."id"; args=("title", ...)
```

I tried to execute this query in PgAdmin. It returned this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "args"
```

What can be wrong?

**UPD:** Here is tracback for InternalError:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/<Path to my app>/views.py" in master
  115.             ad = form.save()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  364.                              fail_message, commit, construct=False)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_instance
  86.         instance.save()
File "<Path to my app>/models.py" in save
  145.         super(Ad, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  463.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  551.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  203.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1576.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  910.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

**UPD2:**

My model has overwrited save method:

```
def save(self,  *args, **kwargs):
    self.title = self.model.brand.name + " " + self.model.name
    super(Ad, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Data is proccessed by view which uses `ModelForm` (which gets data from POST). Form was validated (form.is_valid()) before saving.

Comment: Do you need `;` before `args`? Is the query generated by django or you doing it?

Comment: This query is generated by django. This is a problem. Wait a min. I'll add trace back

Comment: some code of view, model will also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you've got a bug in your code that generates the INSERT statement through Django. It's hard to say what the problem is without seeing that code. The semicolon in the SQL you posted ends a valid-looking SQL statement.

The `args=("title", ...)` portion doesn't look SQL to me. Check your code to see what might be accidentally appending that to whatever generates the SQL.

Comment: Yes, args=() is a python list with pythonic data like `None`, `u'string'`.  But why? I just use `form = MyForm(request.POST)` and then `save` method. So it works only with django api.

Comment: This is very silly, but (`args=(...)` in sql query) wasn't Django problem nor fantastic. It's just me coped debug output wrong. The actual problem was `null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint` which is easily fixable by editing my view. Thanks!